# How to find the Center Coordinate of Rectangle?

Tags: math, geometry, formula

I have drawn a rectangle. I know its (x1,y1) Top Left and (x2,y2) Bottom Right coordinates.. I also have the height h and width w of drawn rectangle.. How can I find the center coordinates (x,y) ?

I am currently using the following formula.

```
(x,y) = (x2 + x1)/2, (y2+y1)/2
```

It gives the correct y coordinate but no luck in x.

Comment: LOL pity -me! I was taking wrong x coordinates :)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about mathematics unrelated to programming.

Comment: There is a such thing as mathematics in programming and as such sometimes the way you get that mathematical result may require some explanation on how to achieve it in the language you are programming in. I didn't think this was off topic at all.

Comment: This was by no stretch of the imagination unrelated. I am using OpenCV to do face recognition and there is no Rect method to get the center of a rectangle. I will be using this formula.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

The center of rectangle is the midpoint of the diagonal end points of rectangle.

Here the midpoint is `( (x1 + x2) / 2, (y1 + y2) / 2 )`.

That means:
`xCenter = (x1 + x2) / 2`
`yCenter = (y1 + y2) / 2`

Let me know your code.

Comment: I think that it also can be - ( (x1*2)/2 , (y1*2)/2 )

Comment: @OrlovAndrey only if the rectangle is a square.  Not all rectangles are squares.

Comment: @OrlovAndrey

if top left is 0,0 and top right is 30,0
and bottom left is 0,40 bottom right is 30, 40

You would add 0 + 30 and then divide by 2 to get x and do the same with y values.

Answer (score 31):

```
Center x = x + 1/2 of width

Center y = y + 1/2 of height
```

If you know the width and height already then you only need one set of coordinates.

Comment: I know it like this also but it was not working. Had to substract the width and the height of the element im trying to place.

Answer (score 3):

We can calculate using mid point of line formula,

```
centre (x,y) =  new Point((boundRect.tl().x+boundRect.br().x)/2,(boundRect.tl().y+boundRect.br().y)/2)
```