# Get center of rectangle opencv python

Tags: python, opencv

```
import cv2
import numpy as np



blank = np.zeros((720,720,3), np.uint8)
cv2.rectangle(blank,(168,95),(2,20),(0,0,255),3)
cv2.rectangle(blank,(366,345),(40,522),(0,255,0),3)
cv2.imshow('test', blank)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[image]

How can I get the coordinates of the centers of each rectangle ? I'm trying to draw a line covering the distance between them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find the Center Coordinate of Rectangle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9734821/how-to-find-the-center-coordinate-of-rectangle)

Comment: Take a piece of square or graph paper (or print one of the many templates found on the internet), draw axes and a rectangle, and think about it for a few minutes.

Answer (score 8):

cv2.rectangle only draws the rectangle itself, it doesn't return a class or store meta-data. Since you already have the points for the corners that define the rectangles, getting the centers of each is trivial, just ((x1+x2)/2, (y1+y2)/2). Thus, you can draw the line between them like:

```
rect1center = ((168+2)/2, (95+20)/2)
rect2center = ((366+40)/2, (345+522)/2)
cv2.line(blank, rect1center, rect2center, color, thickness)
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know which of the arguments were x and y coordinates !

Comment: One thing that may help: most points in opencv are stored as a two-tuple with the following form:  ```point = (x, y)```. There are some cases where they take the form ```pixel = (row, col)```, but in general they are the former

Answer (score 0):

The above method gave me an error like

```
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.5) :-1: error: (-5:Bad argument) in function 'line'
> Overload resolution failed:
>  - Can't parse 'pt1'. Sequence item with index 0 has a wrong type
>  - Can't parse 'pt1'. Sequence item with index 0 has a wrong type
```

so i tried the following method and it worked for me:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

blank = np.zeros((720,720,3), np.uint8)
cv2.rectangle(blank,(168,95),(2,20),(0,0,255),3)
cv2.rectangle(blank,(366,345),(40,522),(0,255,0),3)

rect1x, rect1y = ((168+2)/2, (95+20)/2)
rect2x, rect2y = ((366+40)/2, (345+522)/2)
rect1center = int(rect1x),int(rect1y)
rect2center = int(rect2x),int(rect2y)
print(rect1center)
print(rect2center)
cv2.line(blank, (rect1center), (rect2center), (0,0,255), 4)

cv2.imshow('test', blank)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```