# How can I get the center coordinates of a rectangle in javafx?

Tags: javafx

do anyone has an idea on how to get the center-coordinates of an rectangle in javafx?
Is there a method or an algorithm for that, couse I want to know the center-position while the rectangle is rotating and moving.
I couldn't find a solution on the web so I hope one of you can help me.

Answer (score 2):

You can calculate the center of a rectangle like this:

```
center.x = position.x + width / 2
center.y = position.y + height / 2
```

Or if you represent your rectangle as 2 points (two opposite corners) you would have to use the following formula:

```
p0
+-------+
|       |
|       |
+-------+
       p1

center.x = (p0.x + p1.x) / 2
center.y = (p0.y + p1.y) / 2
```

Also:
A quick google yields [How to find the Center Coordinate of Rectangle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9734821/how-to-find-the-center-coordinate-of-rectangle) as first result...

Comment: thanks for your answer but I think this method is useless while the rectangle is rotating, isn't it?

Comment: It works perfectly fine for a rotated rectangle. Imagine drawing a diagonal line through your rectangle and then marking the center of this line. It will also work on a scaled, translated and sheared rectangle.

Comment: Wait... do you know the rotated points? Or is that your problem?

Comment: Sorry I am a beginner. How do one keep track of these opposite points? As far as I know the methods .getTranslatex() / .getTranslateY() always takes the most left and the uppest corner of the rectangle.

Comment: Alright, please specify your question above, this won't get us anywhere unless I know how you do things. How do you represent the rectangle in your code (eg. two points or as `javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle`). And how do you transform it? (eg. you transform the `GraphicsContext` and draw it) A minimal, complete, and verifiable example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be much appreciated. Then we can see how to fix your problem.

Comment: Note you probably want to compute the center based on the rectangle's [`boundsInParent`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/Node.html#boundsInParentProperty) property; then all transforms are taken into account.

Comment: That's a good point, assuming he is not drawing the rectangle on a canvas @Slaw

Answer (score 1):

Use the `localToParent` method to convert the center of the rectangle to the coordinate system of the parent.

The center of the `Rectangle` in local coordinates is

```
x = rect.x + rect.width/2
y = rect.y + rect.height/2
```

**Example**

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(50, 50, 100, 100);
    Translate translate = new Translate();
    Rotate rotate = new Rotate(0, 0, 0);
    rect.getTransforms().addAll(translate, rotate);
    Circle circle = new Circle(5, Color.RED);

    AnimationTimer timer = new AnimationTimer() {

        @Override
        public void handle(long now) {
            double d = now / 5_000_000_000d;
            rotate.setAngle(d * 360);
            translate.setX((d % 2) * 300);
            translate.setY((d % 3) * 150);

            // set circle center to coordinates of rect's center
            Point2D center = rect.localToParent(rect.getX() + 0.5 * rect.getWidth(),
                    rect.getY() + 0.5 * rect.getHeight());
            circle.setCenterX(center.getX());
            circle.setCenterY(center.getY());
        }

    };
    Pane root = new Pane(rect, circle);

    timer.start();

    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 800, 800);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```